# use a directive with public scope as a isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

Some time ago I have written a custom directive and it is now used at many places inside the code (not possible to change it anymore).

It has a public scope and that was fine until today. Now I want to use the same directive twice inside the same controller-scope (parent-scope) but need each directive (child-scopes) to have its own variables (like isolated-scope) and do not mismatch with each other.

Is it possible to insert this directive and declare explicitly to use an isolated scope, even though it is first created with a public scope?
Or maybe a way to restrict it inside the parent-controller?
Or is there any other way how to do it?

ex.

```
// Panel directive
angular.directive('panel', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'panel.html',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true
    }

});

// Parent directive (include more than one 'panel' directives)
angular.directive('parentDirektive'), function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'parent.html',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        controller: function($scope) {
            // I want to set different value for this variable
            // in each 'panel' direktive I add in 'parent.html'.
            $scope.headline = 'this.should.be.unique.in.each.panel.directive';
        }
    }
});
```

parent.html

I want somehow to set the value of 'scope.headline'
 different for each panel occurence in here
 (like isolate the variable in each directive)?!
 But cannot change the scope to isolated in the declaration
 in need it only in this case.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <!-- I want to display 'Title: First Panel' -->
        <panel></panel>

        <!-- I want to display 'Title: Second Panel' -->
        <panel></panel>
    </body>
</html>
```

panel.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Title: {{$scope.headline}}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Directive scope can be either *none*, *inherited*, or *isolate*. It is not clear what you mean by "public scope".

Comment: I edited my question with some examples. thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to add a controller to each component:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <!-- I want to display 'Title: First Panel' -->
        <panel ng-controller="firstPanelController"></panel>

        <!-- I want to display 'Title: Second Panel' -->
        <panel ng-controller="secondPanelController"></panel>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `ng-controller` directive creates a new inherited scope on which the controller can place properties that superceed parent scope properties.

Answer (score 2):

the best is to use an isolated scope, for example.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

myApp.directive('myDirective', () => ({
    template: `<div>{{vm.aaa}}</div>`,
    controller: 'myDirectiveCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    restrict: 'EA',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
        aaa: "=" // use if you want to pass varuble to the directive
    },
    bindToController: true,
}));
myApp.controller('myDirectiveCtrl', function () {
    console.log(this.aaa); // will come beck undefind
    vm.$postLink = () => {
        console.log(this.aaa); // return the passed value
    };
});
```

every directive has his owen scope

```
<my-directive aaa="'77'"></my-directive>
<my-directive aaa="'99'"></my-directive>
```

be advised the controller will not work on the transclude area

Comment: I added some examples in my question above. The problem is that I cannot change the scope of the directive to 'isolated' because this directive is used at more places (no-isolated is needed). What I want is to simulate a isolated-like scope only in this case.